# Show that an integer in an odd base system is odd in the base 10 system...

Tags: number-theory, puzzle

Show that an integer in an odd base system is odd in the base 10 system if and only if it has an odd number of odd digits.

I have an idea of how the proof should go in my head, but how do I express the number in the odd base system?
Would this be appropriate?

Suppose a number abc in base d, where d is an odd base.
Let a,b and c be odd digits. Then in base 10, abc=a*d^2+b*d+c
Let a=2j+1, b=2k+1, c=2m+1 and d=2n+1
Thus, abc=a*d^2+b*d+c=(2j+1)(4n^2+4n+1)+(2k+1)(2n+1)+(2m+1)=2(4j(n^2)+2(n^2)+4nj+2kn+3n+j+k+m+1)+1 which is odd.
Then repeat but use two of the digits as odd and one as even.

Is there a better way to generalize this proof?

Comment: Let $b$ be our base. Then our number is $a_nb^n+a_{n-1}b^{n-1}+\cdots +a_1b+a_0$.

Comment: I don't think "if and only if" is a right word though. Since $3$, which is an odd number, has representation $10$, which has two digits in it, in base $3$.

Answer (score 2):

You have the basic idea.  You can represent an $n$ digit number in base $d$ as $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_id^i$, where $a_i$ are the digits.  I would then argue $\pmod 2$, so $d \equiv 1 \pmod 2$ and $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_id^i\equiv \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_i \pmod 2$ Now if you know the sum of an odd number of odd numbers is odd you are home.